# How can I convert an onload into Async/Await

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following Javascript that import an csv file I would like to use as async since the browser freeze for large record

But I can't seem to sort it out in my head how to do this.

```
 $('#lnkUpload').click(function () {
    var FileToRead = document.getElementById('UserFile');
    if (FileToRead.files.length > 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // assign function to the OnLoad event of the FileReader  
        // non synchronous event, therefore assign to other method  
        reader.onload = Load_CSVData;
        // call the reader to capture the file  
        reader.readAsText(FileToRead.files.item(0));
    }


});


function Load_CSVData(e) {



    CSVLines = e.target.result.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    $CSVLines = CSVLines.slice(1);
    $.each($CSVLines, function (i, item) {
        if (item === "\n" || item.trim().length <= 2) { return; }
        else {
            var element = item.split(","); // builds an array from comma delimited items  
            var LAccount_id = (element[0] === undefined) ? "" : element[0].trim();
            var LJV = (element[1] === undefined) ? "" : element[1].trim();







        self.userModel.push(new userModel()
            .Account_id(LAccount_id)
            .JV(LJV))
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: How is this connected to C#?

Comment: I see you're removing all your entries from (what is presumably) a knockout observable array, then adding new ones in one at a time.  If there's a lot of data there, you're probably better off loading it all into an array, then updating the knockout observable array just once with that array.  It could be the constant redrawing that is causing the delays/freezing you're seeing.

Comment: thanks  @JamesThorpe